# How to grey out a checkbox (disable input) in Lotus Notes (Version 8.5.2FP4)

Tags: checkbox, lotus-notes, disabled-input

What is the way to grey out a Lotus Notes checkbox?
I use the Input Enabled calculation, but it disappears when the Value is @TRUE. I just want the input disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Create a second checkbox, set it to the type "Computed for Display". Then you use a hide-when formula to display the computed one and hide the editable one based on your criteria.

Comment: Also (1) be sure that the two checkboxes are in separate paragraphs; and (2) the easiest way to assure that only one of the checkboxes is visible at a time is to create one formula to hide one of them, and use the exact same formula surrounded by !( ) for the other.

Answer (score 1):

The values of `CheckBox` must be a text values. `@True` is wrong value for `CheckBox`. So, if your `CheckBox` field contains right values, then you can use `Input Enabled` calculation.
For example, if your `CheckBox` have this choices:
[image: Choices]
then if the value of `CheckBox` is `"Value0":"Value2"` and `Input Enabled` calculation is evaluates to `@False` then you receive this result:
[image: Result]